# Sending variables to the object store in Mule

Tags: variables, mule

Can somebody point me to a sample where variables are sent to the object store and the re used after the transport barrier has been crossed ?

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

To store-retrieve properties (and anything else) into the object store, you can leverage the [object store module](http://mulesoft.github.io/mule-module-objectstore/mule/objectstore-config.html)

Comment: Hi thank you for your feedback. I know I should use the object store module. I am looking for a working sample. Regards.

Comment: The link to the object store is no longer valid.